Error 404 imágenes (estaticas) .Net 8 en IIS
Tengo un proyecto en .Net 8, en la carpeta wwwroot se alojan imágenes, js, css ...
Ejecutando el proyecto todo va bien pero cuando se publica el proyecto en el IIS no se visualizan las imágenes, no las encuentra.

En program ya he agregado la instrucción app.UseStaticFiles();
Al momento de querer mostrar la imagen he probado lo siguiente:
"Carpeta"/Imagen"
"/Carpeta"/Imagen"
"~/Carpeta"/Imagen"

Al realizar la publicación todas las imágenes marcan error 404.

Y las imagenes estan publicadas?

Si, físicamente se encuentran en la publicación

sera porque la carpeta de las imagenes se llama images????

No creo que tenga algo que ver, tengo entendido que net core configura los archivos contenidos en la carpeta wwwroot como estaticos, esto hace que el propio net core ubique esos tipos de archivos al momento de la compilación, pero cuando publico no encuentra las imagenes

Lo que he descubierto es que si publico el proyecto como sitio web todo funciona bien ya que la ruta es localhost/nombre control
En cambio si lo publico como aplicación dentro del Default Web Site antepone el nombre de la aplicación antes del control localhost/nombre aplicación/nombre control. Como podría publicarlo como aplicación sin que pase lo de la ruta?

¿Existe alguna propiedad que tenga que agregar en el program para que esto no suceda ?

ni idea , no veo el codigo con el que se mete la imagen estatica como para determinar si hay un objeto al que se le pueda agregar una propiedad ...

No seria una propiedad para agregar imágenes estaticas, es una propiedad en el program para que al publicar en una aplicación web en iis dentro del Default Web Site no coloque en la URL el nombre de la aplicación

Actualmente la aplicación coloca la url de esta forma localhost/nombre aplicación/nombre control y lo que yo estoy buscando es que no coloque el nombre que se le da a la publicación y la URL quede de esta forma localhost/nombre control

Ya he solucionado el problema, en program.cs hay que colocar la siguiente linia de código
app.UsePathBase("/Alias"); 

Y en cada referencia hay que colocar el mismo alias, de preferencia debe ser el alias que se le da a la aplicación en IIS.
<script src="~/Alias/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>


En el IIS del servidor revisa los permisos de la carpeta donde estan las imagenes

